# Unable to access mongo entry by "id"

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

I have a Mongo Document with some fields (_id, id, name, status, etc...). I wrote a typical document in a class(like a model would do):

```
class mod(Document):
    id=fields.IntField()  
    name = fields.StringField()
    status=fields.StringField()
    description_summary = fields.StringField()
    _id = fields.ObjectIdField()
```

And with this model, I tried to access them:

```
    >>> from mongoengine import *
    >>> from api.models import *
    >>> connect('doc')
    MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary())
```

I tried to fetch all the entries in the "mod" document: It Worked! I can get all the fields of all the entries (id, name, etc...)

```
    >>> mod_ = mod.objects.all()
    >>> mod_[0].name
    'Name of entry'
    >>> mod_[0].id
    102
```

I tried to filter and return all the entries with the field "status" = "Incomplete": It works, just like before.I tried to filter other fields: it works too

```
    >>> mod_ = mod.objects(status="Incomplete")
    >>> mod_[0].name
    'Name of entry'
    >>> mod_[0].id
    102
```

But When I try to filter with the id I don't manage to get a result:

```
    >>> mod_ = mod.objects(id=102)
    >>> mod_[0].name
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 193, in __getitem__
        return queryset._document._from_son(queryset._cursor[key],
      File "/.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 570, in __getitem__
        raise IndexError("no such item for Cursor instance")
    IndexError: no such item for Cursor instance
    >>> mod_[0].id
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 193, in __getitem__
        return queryset._document._from_son(queryset._cursor[key],
      File "/.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 570, in __getitem__
        raise IndexError("no such item for Cursor instance")
    IndexError: no such item for Cursor instance
```

So I tried with `mod.objects.get(id=102)`

```
>>> mod_ = mod.objects.get(id=102)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 271, in get
    raise queryset._document.DoesNotExist(msg)
api.models.DoesNotExist: mod matching query does not exist.
```

Mod matching query does not exist, so it doesn't recognize the *id* field  but when I write `mod_[0].id` I do have a result, so **what can be wrong?**

EDIT: I believe that when writing mod.objects(id=102), the field *id* is interpreted as the _id. **How can I specify, I want to query by *id* and not *_id*?** My Document is already written, so I cannot change the name of the fields.

Comment: actually mongo can differentiate between id and _id, so it wont consider your id field as default _id field. Querying with id field should work, i think there is no document named id=102 .

Comment: Then it's weird, in my 2 examples (objects.all(), and objects(status="")), If i write mod[0].id, I do have a '102'-id

Comment: i tried the same scenario using id field in mongoshell db.collectionname.find() its getting me proper document

Comment: Indeed, I too manage to get a proper document in the mongoshell, but my problem is in the mongoengine module python

Comment: So, I found about db_field parameter, `mod_id = fields.IntField(db_field='id')`. I still have the same issue, so I don't see what can be the problem.

Comment: same here don't see what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem does not come from the difference between _id and id, like said [@HourGlass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4098064/hourglass). The values of the id field were stored as integer, I wrote fields.IntField() for the id field, and called `mod.objects(id=102)` (without quotes).

But for some reason, I have to write them as fields.StringField(), and call `mod.objects(id='102')`.